# mac var form linq to some instance

Tags: c#, linq

Hi if i create some instance of class products and then take one product from database using LINQ can i map result to this instance?

```
products produkt1 = new products();
var oneProduct= (from p in db.products where p.number == 640 select p)
                .FirstOrDefault();
produkt1 = oneProduct;
```

but of course it doesn't work , how should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
products oneProduct = (from p in db.products
                      where p.number == 640
                      select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
products oneProduct = db.products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.number == 640);
```

You can't map instance from DB onto your, just created instance. You can save a reference to DB instance to your, i.e. replace:

```
 products produkt1 = new products(); // points to the first instance
 produkt1 = query.FirstOrDefault(...); // now points to the second instance. if this was the last reference, object probably will be deleted by GC soon
```

To map how you want isn't possible until your class supports this directly, i.e. via some method:

```
class products
{
    public void CloneFrom(products source)
    {
        this.SomeThing = source.SomeThing;
        ...
    }
}
```

in most case this is a bad idea, senseless approach.

Comment: +1 for the dot notation form, which is much simpler IMO. Query expressions are great where appropriate, but there's no reason to use it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
products produkt1 =  db.products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.number == 640);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just edit the selected entity (oneProduct)?

Can you elaborate a little more on what your intention is -- do you want to create a duplicate of the selected entity for the purposes of inserting a new copy as a new row?